# I am getting these errors while running kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting these errors while running the application. Can someone help to fix the bug.

```
Process: app.errandel.android, PID: 29755
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lists of data to pull from, but you arbitrarily pull from both lists using the `position`, which may be bigger than either of them since `getItemCount()` returns the combined size of both lists.

You need to decide which list to pull from based on how big the position is. Something like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position < feedback.size) {
        val feedbackItem = feedback[position]
        itemView.tv_question.text = feedbackItem.questions
        //...
    } else {
        val answersItem = answerss[position - feedback.size]
        holder.itemView.cb_answer.text = answersItem
        //...
    }

}
```

Since you seem to be using a common layout for both types of list item, you will also need to possibly hide and show parts of the layout in the two respective branches of this if/else statement.